# Complexity of continued fraction arithmetic operations

Tags: computational-complexity, continued-fractions

Let $A = [a_0; a_1, \dots]$ and $B = [b_0; b_1, \dots]$ be continued fractions.

Let's say that we want to compute $A+B$ or $A \cdot B$ while staying in the continued fraction representation. So, for example, we're given at most $n$ continued fraction terms of $A$ and $B$, and we want to find first $n$ continued fraction terms of $A+B$ and $A\cdot B$. What is the fastest method to do so in terms of computational complexity?

[Gosper's algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Continued_fraction/Arithmetic) maintains its internal state in the form of a fractional linear transform
$$
L(x, y) = \frac{axy+bx+cy+d}{exy+fx+gy+h}.
$$
To compute $L(A, B)$ it "inputs" coefficients of $A$ and $B$ one by one, changing the transform accordingly, and whenever all candidates for "output" agree with each other, i.e.
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{a}{e}\right\rfloor =
\left\lfloor \frac{b}{f}\right\rfloor = 
\left\lfloor \frac{c}{g}\right\rfloor =
\left\lfloor \frac{d}{h}\right\rfloor,
$$
it prints their value as the next term of $L(A, B)$. This is an ingenious approach, but on practice it seems that the coefficients $a, \dots, h$ can grow uncontrollably large before they agree, leading to something like $O(n^2)$ in terms of computational complexity. to input first $n$ coefficients of $A$ and $B$, and output first $n$ coefficients of $A+B$ or $A \cdot B$.

Are there any bounds on how large intermediate coefficients can become?

I would assume that computing the $n$-th convergent of $A$ and $B$ with divide and conquer approach in $O(n \log^2 n)$, then doing the corresponding operation on the convergents, and converting it back to continued fraction in $O(n \log^2 n)$ with something similar to Half-GCD algorithm for polynomials would have a better complexity.

But are there any publications that study this question rigorously?